# Add Docker’s official GPG key from behind a coorporate firewall

Tags: firewall, docker

I'm using [the official docker installation instructions](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/#install-using-the-repository) to install Docker on one of our internal Debian servers. The installation instructions show one way of installing the key:

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID")/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Our network admin ran "dig download.docker.com" yesterday, and punched a hole in the firewall for these IP addresses. Today I ran the same command, but got a different set of IP addresses. I'm guessing this has something to do with the Cloudfront service.

How can we go about ensuring that we cover the necessary IP addresses to allow the curl-command to run successfully?

PS. I posted this question over at [the Docker forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/add-docker-s-official-gpg-key-from-behind-a-coorporate-firewall/47105), but didn't get any replies so I thought I'd post here as we..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon maintains a list of CloudFront IP addresses for this purpose. It can be found at https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json (look for the entries marked `CLOUDFRONT`).

Probably a better alternative to this strategy (IP filtering) is to put a forwarding proxy in place and move this traffic through the proxy. This way you can do URL filtering, avoiding this issue altogether.

Comment: Thanks! I'll discuss these options with our network admins.